# Did Facebook change completely change their SDK?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, oauth, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've had a working application that connects and registers my users through their **Facebook Accounts** and retrieves some public information. Anyway, the application **stopped** working with Facebook with the new update **(V2.6)**. I haven't changed any of my code, and now it's failing at creating a login URL for Facebook.

Last time I managed to Login successfully was on the **10th of April**. I've read the **Changelog** for **V2.6** but couldn't find anything that would/should change the Login flow. Here is the function that used to generate the Login URL and I would just get asked if I'd allow *"my app"* to access my **Facebook information**, I'd press allow and everything would continue perfectly. Now, I get the *"SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. See the Facebook Help Centre for more information"* error when the generated Login URL is called...

```
        private string GenerateLoginUrlFacebook()
    {

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

        parameters.client_id = Globals.FBapplicationID;
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        parameters.response_type = "token";
        parameters.display = "popup";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Globals.FBextendedPermissionsNeeded))
            parameters.scope = Globals.FBextendedPermissionsNeeded;

        var fb = new FacebookClient();

        Uri loginUri = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

        return loginUri.AbsoluteUri;
        //return @"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=471150563090234&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your version must be deprecated . check version on developer facebook.

Comment: I think I'm using version 2.5 and i'm pretty sure 2.6 is now out... But i went to Nuget Manager and couldnt find any available updates, or is that not the way to do it? sorry, I'm not very experienced